# Game Maker - Checking position of multiple objects of same name

Tags: position, game-maker

How do you check the position values of two of the same object in a room? I have two of the same object in my room and need to find the x and y positioning of each.

Comment: I've attempted to assign obj_enemy_run.x and obj_enemy_run.y but it just chooses the enemy closest to the top left corner of the screen.

Comment: `instance_find`, `with` and a lot of another ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
with (objName) {
    // now x is each objName.x, and y is each objName.x, while to access object from which you called you need to use other.xxx (except VAR defined variables)
}
```

for example, to get all X positions:

```
var xpos = [], _a = 0;
with (objName) {
    xpos[a++] = x;
}
// xpos[0] is x of first object, xpos[1] of second etc.
```